# Proteus Ground Plane with thin trace in Pad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus

I am doing a project on Proteus Ares and applying a ground plan.
However, the points of the terminals that are connected to ground to ground-pad connection is by a thin trail.

Is there any way to adjust to the ground and the point does not have that spacing?

Below a example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Don't have that tool myself but if you want to get rid of the thermal reliefs try right clicking that via and seeing if there is an option for pad shape.   If that fails try looking up thermal relief in your help files.

Comment: There might also be some options if you click on that flood or plane itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found!

Right-click in ground plane and uncheck the option "Relieve Pins"

Thank you "Some Hardware Guy"

[image]